# find and delete lines without string pattern in text files

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find out how to use powershell to find and delete lines without certain string pattern in a set of files. For example, I have the following text file:

`111111

22x222

333333

44x444`

This needs to be turned into:

`22x222

44x444`

given that the string pattern of 'x' is not in any of the other lines.

How can I issue such a command in powershell to process a bunch of text files?

thanks.

Comment: Is the whitespace before some lines intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dir | foreach { $out = cat $_ | select-string x; $out | set-content $_  }
```

The `dir` command lists the files in the current directory; the `foreach` goes through each file; `cat` reads the file and pipes into `select-string`; `select-string` finds the lines that contains the specific pattern, which in this case is "x"; the result of `select-string` is stored in `$out`; and finally, `$out` is written to the same file with `set-content`.

We need the temporary variable `$out` because you cannot read and write the same file at the same time.

Comment: What if I need to process "x" or "y" or "z"? How do I form the select-string to take all those as 'or'?

Comment: @Niner It's a regular expression so you could do `select-string "x|y|z"`. To learn more take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315294.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

This will process all txt files from the working directory. Each file content is checked and only lines that have 'x' in them are allowed to pass on. The result is written back to the file.

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object{
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName | Where-Object {$_ -match 'x'}
    $content | Out-File $_.FullName
}
```